# Determine Which Half of Screen

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Winforms app.  This has a form that launches other forms, let's call it the controlling form.  I would like the controlling form to look and see if it is in the top half of the current screen or bottom half.  If it is in the top half, the other forms should appear underneath it.  If it is the bottom half, other forms should appear above it.  Also, please note that the users of this app have many (4-6) screens.

My theory is, if we look at height of current screen and divide by two, this tells us the Y co-ordinate of the half way point.

I have the following code:

```
gadgetBase.Show(); // Gadget base is another form
var thisScreen = Screen.FromHandle(this.Handle);
if (this.Location.Y > thisScreen.Bounds.Y/2)
{
    //  we're in the top half
    gadgetBase.Top = this.Bottom + SystemInformation.BorderSize.Height;
    gadgetBase.Left = this.Left;
}
else
{
    //  we're in the bottom half
    gadgetBase.Top = this.Top + SystemInformation.BorderSize.Height + gadgetBase.Height;
    gadgetBase.Left = this.Left;

}
```

However, `thisScreen.Bounds.Y` is always zero.  This suggests that I am not using the correct property. Can you suggest how I should do this?  (I don't mind reworking if my approach is not great.)

Comment: If (this.Location.Y < thisScreen.Top + thisScreen.Height / 2)

Comment: Will the form necessarily always be in one half or the other? What happens if it's straddling the half-way line? (Also, suspect a typo since you have two sentences that discuss what happens when it's in the top half, with contradictory outcomes)

Comment: @damien_the_unbeliever edited, good spot. If it is in half way line then either would suffice. Only trying to avoid an issue if the controller is very near the top or bottom. I will post full answer code tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the Resolution of the Screen?

```
Screen ThisScreen = Screen.FromControl(TestForm);
MessageBox.Show(ThisScreen.Bounds.Width.ToString() + "x" + ThisScreen.Bounds.Height.ToString());
```

Comment: This does not account for anything other than primary screen.  In my sample above, 'thisScreen' does not have a Resolution property.

Comment: And if you use ´Screen[] MyScreens = Screen.AllScreens´ ?

Comment: Not sure how that helps get current screen?

Comment: With the `Screen.FromControl` Property?

Comment: Example:

`Screen ThisScreen = Screen.FromControl(TestForm);
MessageBox.Show(ThisScreen.Bounds.Width.ToString() + "x" + ThisScreen.Bounds.Height.ToString());`

Comment: I now have this working.  If you wish turn your comments into an answer to the question I will accept and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Code below answers my original question: determines which half of screen and aligns child forms accordingly:

```
                gadgetBase.Show();
                var thisScreen = Screen.FromControl(this);
                if (this.Location.Y < thisScreen.Bounds.Height/2)
                {
                    //  we're in the top half
                    gadgetBase.Top = this.Bottom + SystemInformation.BorderSize.Height;
                    gadgetBase.Left = this.Left;
                }
                else
                {
                    //  we're in the bottom half
                    gadgetBase.Top = this.Top - SystemInformation.BorderSize.Height - gadgetBase.Height;
                    gadgetBase.Left = this.Left;

                }
```